# How does logging work if I have slf4j-api, log4j, slf4j-log4j12 and commons-logging in classpath?

Tags: java, spring, log4j, slf4j, apache-commons-logging

In our `build.gradle:`

```
 dependencies {
        // Logging
        compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:$slf4jVersion"
        compile "log4j:log4j:$log4jVersion"
        compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:$slf4jVersion"
        ....
     }
```

In code we use classes from `slf4j` library.
Thus it looks like this:

[image]

Also we use Spring framework. It uses `commons-logging` inside. There are no exclusions of `commons-logging` in our configuration. But I see Spring logs in our log files. And I don't understand how does it work (I see that it works). Is our configuration correct?

### P.S.

From my point of view I should add `jcl-over-slf4j` and exclude `commons-logging`  but I see that now it works correctly.

Is concatenation of circumstances the expected behavior?

Comment: Are you sure that spring is not dragging in the jcl-over-slf4j? Have you examined your actual classpath when you are running?

Comment: @bmargulies, please provide way to examine this ?

Comment: Well, there's always `ps -eafwwww` to examine the command line. I imagine that gradle has some way to be rendered more verbose, but I don't know it well enough to know what it is.

Comment: @bmargulies, **ps -eafwwww** does it linux command ?

Comment: Yes. A Linux command

Comment: @bmargulies in idea I see http://dl2.joxi.net/drive/2016/09/07/0005/3037/338909/09/2b71ceaf17.jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122844/discussion-between-bmargulies-and-gstackoverflow).